# SqlDataSource Procedure or function expects parameter which was not specified

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqldatasource

I have a SqlDataSource that I am attempting to add an UpdateCommand to so I can call a stored procedure when a GridView's update button is selected.  I am doing this in code behind due to the fact that I need to call one of two procedures, depending on if the record already exists in the database table (INSERT for new, UPDATE for existing record).  When I set the Updateparameters in the RowUpdating event, I get the following exception:

> **Procedure or function 'usp_TestLogInsert' expects parameter '@Status', which was not supplied.**

Here is the ASP code and code behind for this.  I am explicitly creating the parameters in the code behind, so I do not see why I get this exception.  I have already verified that these are the same parameters needed for the stored procedure.

C#

```
protected void gvChecklist_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    SQLConnections sql = new SQLConnections();
    SqlDataSource dsChecklist = (SqlDataSource)LoginView1.FindControl("dsChecklist");
    var dd = (DropDownList)gvChecklist.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddStatus");
    var status = dd.SelectedValue;
    var testID = sql.SQLSelectSingle(String.Format("SELECT ID FROM Automation.manual.Tests WHERE Task = '{0}'", (String)e.OldValues["Task"]), "pwautosql01");
    string user = Page.User.Identity.Name;
    string notes = (String)e.NewValues["Notes"];
    string jira = (String)e.NewValues["JiraTicket"];
    var dbID = e.NewValues["ID"];
    string build = "TODO";

    if (dbID == null) //Record does not exist in TestLog, INSERT a new one
    {
        dsChecklist.UpdateCommand = "[Automation].[manual].[usp_TestLogInsert]";
        dsChecklist.UpdateCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
        dsChecklist.UpdateParameters.Add("@Status", TypeCode.Int32, status);
        dsChecklist.UpdateParameters.Add("@TestID", TypeCode.Int32, testID);
        dsChecklist.UpdateParameters.Add("@TestedBy", TypeCode.String, user);
        dsChecklist.UpdateParameters.Add("@Notes", TypeCode.String, notes);
        dsChecklist.UpdateParameters.Add("@JiraTicket", TypeCode.String, jira);
        dsChecklist.UpdateParameters.Add("@Build", TypeCode.String, build);

        dsChecklist.Update();
    }
    //else //Record already exists in TestLog. UPDATE
    //{
        //TODO
    //}
}
```

ASP

```
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upGridView" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="gvChecklist" runat="server" 
                    AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataSourceID="dsChecklist"
                    AutoGenerateEditButton="true" onrowupdating="gvChecklist_RowUpdating">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblStatus" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Status") %>' />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddStatus" runat="server" DataTextField="Status" DataValueField="ID" DataSourceID="dsStatus" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Division" 
                            HeaderText="Division"
                            readonly="true" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Application"
                            HeaderText="Application"
                            readonly="true" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Task"
                            HeaderText="Task"
                            readonly="true" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="TestedBy" HeaderText="Tested By" readonly="true"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Notes" HeaderText="Notes" ReadOnly="false"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="JiraTicket"
                            HeaderText="JIRA Ticket"
                            readonly="false" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="gvChecklist" />
        </Triggers>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsChecklist" SelectCommand=" SELECT l.ID, d.division, c.Context AS Application, t.Task, l.TestedBy, l.Notes, l.JiraTicket, s.Status
                                                        FROM Automation.manual.Tests t
                                                        OUTER APPLY 
                                                            (SELECT TOP 1 *
                                                            FROM Automation.manual.TestLog l
                                                            WHERE l.TestID = t.ID 
                                                            ORDER BY l.Date DESC) l
                                                        INNER JOIN Automation.dbo.Context c ON  c.ID = t.Context
                                                        INNER JOIN Automation.dbo.Division d ON d.ID = t.Division
                                                        LEFT OUTER JOIN Automation.manual.Status s ON s.ID = l.Status"
                                                       UpdateCommand=""
                       runat="server" 
                       ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AutomationDBConnectionString %>"  />

   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsStatus" SelectCommand="SELECT ID, Status FROM Automation.manual.Status"                               
                      runat="server" 
                      ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AutomationDBConnectionString %>">
                      </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: When you step through your code, does `var status` come back with an actual value?

Comment: Yes it does. It is assigned a string value.

Comment: Shot in the dark, but try casting it to an Int32 when you pull it from 'dd', assuming status is an 'int' in your table.  I'm assuming it is supposed to be 'int' from your 'UpdateParameters.Add' method on 'status'.  I wouldn't think this would be the issue because you have it as a var, but doesn't hurt to make sure.

Comment: The value property for UpdateParameters must be a string.

Comment: You have it as TypeCode.Int32.

Comment: And try doing InsertParameters instead of UpdateParameters on your dsCheckList.

Comment: In the database, it must be an int.  However, the parameter for UpdateParameters.Add must be a string for the value property.

Comment: Try leaving out the @ before the parameter names, I think the SqlDataSource adds it for you

Comment: Yes, that allows dsChecklist.Update to execute.  However, when that event is finished I get a new error... Procedure or function usp_TestLogInsert has too many arguments specified.

Comment: Is TestID an identity column?

Comment: No, it is a Foreign Key to another table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to leave out the @ before the parameter names, the SqlDataSource adds it for you. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad.aspx)

Also try adding the parameters when you instantiate the data source then setting their values in your code behind:

```
<UpdateParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="Status"   Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="TestID"  Type="Int32" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="TestedBy"    Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Notes"       Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="JiraTicket"     Type="String" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="Build" Type="String" />
</UpdateParameters>
```

then:

```
if (dbID == null) //Record does not exist in TestLog, INSERT a new one
{
    dsChecklist.UpdateCommand = "[Automation].[manual].[usp_TestLogInsert]";
    dsChecklist.UpdateCommandType = SqlDataSourceCommandType.StoredProcedure;
    dsChecklist.UpdateParameters["@Status"].Value = status;
    dsChecklist.UpdateParameters["@TestID"].Value = testID;
    dsChecklist.UpdateParameters["@TestedBy"].Value = user;
    dsChecklist.UpdateParameters["@Notes"].Value = notes;
    dsChecklist.UpdateParameters["@JiraTicket"].Value = jira;
    dsChecklist.UpdateParameters["@Build"].Value = build;

    dsChecklist.Update();
}
```

Comment: This works and the stored procedure executes, I can see the values in the database table.  But when the event exits, `Procedure or function usp_TestLogInsert has too many arguments specified.` is thrown.

Comment: You'll need to clear the parameters for subsequent calls or just update their values. You're probably adding them multiple times.

Comment: When I call `dsChecklist.UpdateParameters.Clear();` the original issue arises again.  Where would I clear the parameters to prevent them from being added again?

Comment: Sorry you misunderstood. You can either clear the list after the call then add them again or leave them and update their values. The point is to ensure that when you're about to make the call you have the correct number of parameters.

Comment: Could you add some example code by chance?  I think I am still missing something.  I am clearing the list right before the event finishes, which throws the exception.

Comment: I can't post code right now but could you try adding the parameters when you instantiate the data source and just setting the values when you make the call? Also does your solution allow multiple concurrent calls to Update?

Comment: The datasource is created in the Asp code, however I do not call it in code behind until creating an instance in the RowUpdating event.  Are you suggesting I create the parameters in the Asp page, and assign the values in the event?

Comment: Bingo! Omitting the '@' in the parameter name was most definitely the issue I was having